# NestJS Mock RabbitMQ in Jest

Tags: jestjs, rabbitmq, nestjs

I have an AppModule file as follows:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { RabbitMQModule } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq'

@Module({
    imports: [
        RabbitMQModule.forRoot(RabbitMQModule, {
            exchanges: [
                {
                    name: 'my_rabbit',
                    type: 'direct',
                },
            ],
            uri: process.env.RABBITMQ_URI,
            connectionInitOptions: { wait: true },
        }),
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have tried to mock rabbitmq using `@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq` like this:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { RabbitMQModule } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq'

beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [
                AppModule
            ],
        })
            .overrideProvider(AmqpConnection)
            .useValue(createMock<AmqpConnection>())
            .compile()
    })
```

This is giving me error:

```
[Nest] 2745  - 24/07/2022, 17:02:54   ERROR [AmqpConnection] Disconnected from RabbitMQ broker (default)
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5672
```

If i mock the whole rabbitmq module like:

```js
jest.mock('@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq')
```

I will get errors like:

```
Nest cannot create the AppModule instance.
    The module at index [0] of the AppModule "imports" array is undefined.
```

Has anyone successfully mocked RabbitMQ? Please assist if possible.

Comment: Did you solve this? The answer below didn't quite work for me.

Comment: @Scott-MEARN-Developer I just posted my answer. Please see below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that `AppModule` has the `RabbitMQModule`, which is trying to connect. `overrideProvider` does not prevent the `RabbitMQModule` within the `AppModule` from instantiating, and hence the error.

There are a few ways to solve this.

### Option 1: Re-create the module

The simplest way is to not import `AppModule`, and re-create the module  with whatever imports/providers it has. In this case, there's only `RabbitMQModule`. It returns a few providers, but typically you only need to provide `AmqpConnection`. So for this, we only needed to provide a mock like this:

```js
import { AmqpConnection } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq'
import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended'

beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [],
        providers: [
            { provide: AmqpConnection, useValue: mock<AmqpConnection>() }
    })
    .compile()
})
```

However, in most instances, a module can grow to have a lot of imports and providers. Re-constructing it is tedious, and you want to be able to just import it, and write `__mocks__` to allow it to run in the test environment.

### Option 2: Write a node_modules mock

You can mock node modules in jest by writing the a manual mock (see https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks).

However, for NestJS modules, it usually very troublesome as you need to read the source code and "re-construct" the Nest module. Sometimes the source code is not straight forward.

In this case, the `@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq` mock looks like this:

#### Simple mock

File: `src/__mocks__/@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq.ts`

(Note: The jest docs said that `__mocks__` should be at the same level with `node_modules`. But that didn't work for me.)

```js
import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended'

// create a deeply mocked module
const rmq = jest.createMockFromModule<typeof import('@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq')>(
    '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq',
)

// all the mocked methods from #createMockFromModule will return undefined
// but in this case, #forRoot needs to return mocked providers
// specifically AmqpConnection, and this is how it is done:
rmq.RabbitMQModule.forRoot = jest.fn(() => ({
    module: rmq.RabbitMQModule,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: rmq.AmqpConnection,
            useValue: mock<typeof rmq.AmqpConnection>(),
        },
    ],
    exports: [rmq.AmqpConnection],
}))

module.exports = rmq
```

#### In-memory instances / Testcontainers

Sometimes you may want to spin up an in-memory instance, or use testcontainer, especially for e2e:

File `src/__mocks__/@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq.ts`

```js
import { AmqpConnection } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq'
import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended'
import { GenericContainer } from 'testcontainers'

const rmq = jest.createMockFromModule<typeof import('@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq')>(
    '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq',
)

rmq.RabbitMQModule.forRoot = jest.fn(() => ({
    module: rmq.RabbitMQModule,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: rmq.AmqpConnection,
            useFactory: async () => {
                const RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER = 'RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER'
                const RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS = 'RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS'
                const PORT = 5672

                const rmqContainer = new GenericContainer('rabbitmq:3.11.6-alpine')
                    .withEnvironment({
                        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER,
                        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS,
                    })
                    .withExposedPorts(PORT)

                const rmqInstance = await rmqContainer.start()
                const port = rmqInstance.getMappedPort(PORT)

                return new AmqpConnection({
                    uri: `amqp://${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}:${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}@localhost:${port}`,
                })
            },
        },
    ],
    exports: [rmq.AmqpConnection],
}))

module.exports = rmq
```

The same concept can be used to write mocks for stuff like TypeORM, Mongo, Redis etc.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem mocking an AmqpConnection like this.

```js
    import { AmqpConnection } from "@nestjs-plus/rabbitmq";
    import { TestingModule, Test } from "@nestjs/testing";
    import { IntegrationQueueService } from "./integration-queue.service";

    describe('IntegrationQueueService', () => {

      type MockType<T> = {
         [P in keyof T]?: jest.Mock<{}>;
      };
  

      const mockFactory: () => MockType<AmqpConnection> = jest.fn(() => ({
         publish: jest.fn(() => AmqpConnection),
      }))

 
      let service: IntegrationQueueService;

      beforeEach(async () => {
         const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                IntegrationQueueService,
                {
                    provide: AmqpConnection,
                    useFactory: mockFactory,
                },
            ],

         })
            .compile();

        service = module.get<IntegrationQueueService> (IntegrationQueueService);
    });


    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

})
```